# Agregar una fondo en angular desde el CSS del componente

Tags: css, angular

Cómo agrego de fondo una imagen desde el componente CSS del componente de Angular? Lo agregué de esta forma:

```
body {
  background-image: url("/assets/img/principal.png") !important;
  background-position: center center !important;
  background-attachment: fixed !important;
  background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
  background-size: cover !important;
}
```

Comment: Como agrego una imagen de fondo. en angular para cada componente, gracias

Comment: Buen dia:
Te marca algun error,abre tu consola, ahi en la seccion de network te debera salir si se encontro la imagen?

Comment: si sale la imagen, lo que pasa es que el css del componente no coge,  ya que en la pagina la imagen sale con un espacio en blanco

Answer (score 1):

No es posible acceder a las propiedades css que no pertenezcan al componente. Para lograr lo que quieres deberas utilizar alguna solucion como `Renderer2`

Este es un ejemplo de uso:

```js
  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {
    
    
    renderer.setStyle(
      document.body,
      "background-image",
      'url("https://concepto.de/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/paisaje-e1549600034372.jpg")'
    );

    
  }
```

[Te dejo un ejemplo funcional](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sdvupf) y la documentacion de [Renderer2](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2)

---

#### Adicional

Te recomiendo hacer esto dentro de un servicio por que cuando abandones el componente el `html` continuará con los mismos estilos y tendrás que duplicar tu código para restablecer cada vez.

Comment: muchas gracias .